# delete sp.listitem in client object

Tags: document-library, splistitem, delete

I've an issue to delete document in a document library.
I did not get any exception but  document is not getting deleted

```
clientContext.Load(oldItem.File); 
oldItem.DeleteObject();
oldItem.Update();
c200.list.Update();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

I've added the update on item and list but nothing change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ListItem.DeleteObject Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listitem.deleteobject(v=office.14).aspx) to delete the document item from a Library, for example:

```
var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
var listItem = list.GetItemById(listItemId);
listItem.DeleteObject();
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Hi, i try this but still doesn't work without error

Answer (score 0):

Try following one

var siteUrl = '/sites/MySiteCollection';

function deleteListItem() {

```
this.itemId = 2;

var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Announcements');

this.oListItem = oList.getItemById(itemId);

oListItem.deleteObject();

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
```

}

function onQuerySucceeded() {

```
alert('Item deleted: ' + itemId);
```

}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

```
alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
```

}

ref link for basic operation on sharepoint list.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185011%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Comment: This is JavaScript code, the code in the question is c#. Your code is besides the different languages the same as Vadim's

Comment: did you try this one  <------------->  string siteUrl = "http://servername:2525/";  
            ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);  
            List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("TestList");  
            ListItem oListItem = oList.GetItemById('5');           
            oListItem.DeleteObject();  
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();